# PHP+SQL scoreboard issue

Tags: php

So I have made a ScoreBoard system , But whenever My adding/updating code block runs it fetchs me a 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on the line that holds the mysqli_query(); line like if It's failing , Here's my code .

```
<form method="post" action="">
<center>
<font color="green">Your name Max length is 15</font>
<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="15">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</center>
</form>
<font color='red'><center>
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['username']))
{
$link =  mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
// $getname = $_POST['username'];
$getname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['username']);
$percentage = "10";
$querycheck = ("SELECT * from scoreboard where name = $getname")
$result = mysqli_query($link, $querycheck);
if (mysql_num_rows($querycheck) > 0)
    {
    $queryexist = ("UPDATE scoreboard set percentage = 20 where name = $getname");
    $resultexist = mysqli_query($link, $queryexist);
    echo "<center><font color='green' size='2'>Your score has been updated successfuly</font></center>";
    }
else
    {
    $querydoesnt = ("INSERT INTO scoreboard (name,percent) VALUES ('$getname',$percentage)");
    echo "<center><font color='green' size='2'>Your name has been added to the scoreboard successfuly </font></center>!";
    }
?>
</font></center>
```

It fetches me an error that apparently says that there's something wrong with my mysqli_query line , The first one though .

Comment: At `$querycheck` you forgot `;` at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add semicolon `;` also you forgot to end your `if statement`

```
$querycheck = ("SELECT * from scoreboard where name = $getname");
                                                              ^^^^
```

Every PHP statement ends with a semicolon (`;`). PHP doesn't stop reading a statement until it reaches a semicolon. If you leave out the semicolon at the end of a line, PHP continues reading the statement. it reads the two lines as one statement, so it complains with an error message, such as `Parse error: parse error in`...

```
// if statement block

<font color='red'><center>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['username']))
    {
        // your code
    }
</font></center>
```

**NOTE**

You are using `mysqli_` statements, so you need to change `mysql_num_rows()` to `mysqli_num_rows()`

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($querycheck) > 0) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: I fixed it already , But I'm having another error IF you don't mind , I get this 
Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource , It appears to happen in this line if (mysql_num_rows($querycheck) > 0) , Mind telling me why didn't it work ?

Comment: @AhmedMagdy this is because you are using `mysqli_` statements. so change `mysql_num_rows` to `mysqli_num_rows`

Comment: Okay I did this already , Now I get this ,  Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in the same line , I tryed mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_result($querycheck)) , But no luck , Sorry for bothering any ways .

Comment: `mysql_num_rows($querycheck)` should be `mysql_num_rows($result)`

Comment: I did this $querycheck = ("SELECT * from scoreboard where name = $getname");
$result = mysqli_query($link, $querycheck);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) , But it still doesn't work ..

Comment: may be the problem in your select query, try to echo it and then check what output appear..

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot a semicolon on that line

```
$querycheck = ("SELECT * from scoreboard where name = $getname");
                                                                ^
                                                               HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$querycheck = ("SELECT * from scoreboard where name = $getname") ;
```

forgot to put semicolon